# Matching alphanumeric words in a string which are greater than two characters in length

Tags: regex

I have following regex:

```
/^(.*[^0-9])(.[a-z]+[0-9]+[a-z0-9]*|[0-9]+[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*{3,})(.*)$/gm
```

I want to match alphanumeric groups in an URL which are greater than two characters in length. So basically:

In the URL: `/version/a1/type/eg1234/abc`, `eg1234` should match since it's alphanumeric and greater than two in length.

However, while my alphanumeric match logic seems to be working fine, the length condition i.e. `{3,}` isn't being satisfied, as in e.g. `/version/a1/type/`, the regex also matches `a1` which it shouldn't as it's less than two characters in length.

How can I correct my regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
(?=\d+[a-z][a-z\d]*|[a-z\d]*[a-z]\d)[a-z\d]{3,}
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/m1TpwH/1)

This will match only `eg1234` in `/version/a1/type/eg1234/abc`

Comment: Kessely its works fine in isolattion but if put in as a group i.e. `/^(.*[^0-9])((?=\d+[a-z][a-z\d]*|[a-z\d]*[a-z]\d)[a-z\d]{3,})(.*)$/gm` it skips the first characters of the string as in only matches `g1234` in `/version/a1/type/eg1234/abc` instead of `eg1234`

Comment: Tried to customize it a bit with `(?=\d+[a-z][a-z\d]*|.[a-z\d]*[a-z]\d)[a-z\d]{3,}` which solves the above problem, but not sure if its the right solution.

Comment: @Maven You probably mean `^(.*?)((?=\d+[a-z][a-z\d]*|[a-z\d]*[a-z]\d)[a-z\d]{3,})(.*)$`  ? https://regex101.com/r/eES09x/1

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
/\b(?=[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,})(?=(?:[^\/\d]*\d){4,})([^\/]{3,})/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AFT5Pb/1)

Comment: With `/version/a1/type/1eg/abc` nothing will be matched.